# What full frame lens for my new FX camera would be nearest to 18-105mm on my old DX-format D7000?

Tags: nikon, sensor-size, crop-factor, lens-recommendation

I've just gone 'up' to a full frame camera, the D610. Now I have to buy all new lenses. Which would be the nearest to my old 18-105mm that I had on my cropped  D7000?

Comment: 18-105 on DX has same field of view as 27-150 on FX (1.5 crop factor). 28-300VR should be good for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the crop math backwards. :) You went from a 1.5x crop sensor to a 1x crop sensor, so if you multiply the focal lengths for crop by 1.5, you'll get the equivalent FoV full-frame focal lengths.

18 x 1.5 = 27 
105 x 1.5 = 157.5

So any lens that covers 27-157.5 (or an equivalent) will be able to fulfill pretty much the same purpose.  So, in the current Nikon lens lineup, the 28-300 superzoom (which is sort of the FX equivalent of an 18-200), or 24-120 would probably be your closest equivalents.

Comment: @lolwhittingham Most of us don't, until we make "the full frame move." I shoot full-frame, 1.6x APS-C, and 2x four-thirds, so I've gotten good at this kind of math. :)

Comment: thanks to those who've given answers on this to help me.I am the wiser now.